# how to change route pattern in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

In one of my symfony2 bundle I have the following file called registration.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="fos_user_registration_register" pattern="">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Registration:register</default>
    </route>

</routes>
```

and here's my current routing.yml:

```
fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register
```

The issue here is that when I try to print the route I am seeing:

```
fos_user_registration_register                          ANY         ANY    ANY  /register/
```

how do I remove the trailing slash at the end of /register/ ? So I wanted it to be just /register

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not used to routing in XML but don't we have to use `path=` instead `pattern=` ? And if that doesn't solve it you could try this:

YML

```
  fos_user_register:
        resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
        prefix: /
```

XML

```
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="fos_user_registration_register" path="register">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Registration:register</default>
    </route>

</routes>
```

Or perhaps `path="/register"` instead of `path="register"`

Anyhow you should really use the same format everywhere if you can.